# script in mac app temporary location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, perl

I am a bit new to Mac OS X app development and I got stuck with Mac OS moving some Resources to a temp location wereas the her ones remain in the Resources folder. I have searched through google for a few hours and that did not help.

Here is my situation in a little more detail:
I have an application build in Xcode. It consist of an ObjC TaskWrapper and a perl script (main.pl) that is being called after the app is run. There is also an external file(say the name is extrafunctions (no extension)), that I need to load from the perl script in the runtime of application. Both the perl script and the external file are in the Resources folder inside the .app directory after building it from xcode.
After execution the main.pl file is moved to a temp location. The extrafunctions file remains in Resources inside the myMacApp.app folder. Then, when main.pl tries to load extrafunctions (used to be in the same directory) and fails, as extrafunctions has not been copied to the temp folder along. 
I would need to access this extrafunctions file from the perl script, but cannot come across neither a way to get the msipp location, nor a way to let it be copied to the temp location  as well.

Overview:
- main.pl = script in Resources inside myMacApp.app
- extrafunctions = external script to be loaded by main.pl in Resources
- main.pl tries to load extrafunctions: does not work

some code:
install.pl

```
...
if(-f "extrafunctions") {
   open my $fh, "<", "extrafunctions" or die "Could not open extrafunctions : $!";
   $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
   close $fh;
} else {
...
}
```

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide some code in your question./

Comment: Why/when is main.pl being copied to another location?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reactions. The main.pl is being run from some temp location like /var/folders/yl/<some_hash>/T/. I think it's the interpretter moving it? I found that out while doing debugging...

Comment: I think the real question here is what is moving main.pl into temp and why.